# BestHTTP asset download

Tags: c#, unity3d

I'm using the asset BestHTTP in unity and I'm downloading a few image from amazonaws to use as texture. It used to be one image, but now I have a few.

I was not able to shorten it. When I'm trying to do it in a foreach loop loop it is misbehaving.

Could someone help me to optimize this working code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
{
    dealer_img += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;
    dealer_img += ",";
}
string[] newLinks = dealer_img.Split(',');

new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("**************************.amazonaws.com/resources/" 
    + "dealer/pic/" + newLinks[0]),
    (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res)
    =>
    {
        var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
        tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
        uitex[0].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
    }).Send();

new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("**************************.amazonaws.com/resources/"
    + "dealer/pic/" + newLinks[1]),
    (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res)
    =>
    {
        var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
        tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
        uitex[1].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
    }).Send();

new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("**************************.amazonaws.com/resources/"
    + "dealer/pic/" + newLinks[2]),
    (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res)
    =>
    {
        var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
        tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
        uitex[2].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
    }).Send();

new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("**************************.amazonaws.com/resources/"
    + "dealer/pic/" + newLinks[3]),
    (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res)
    =>
    {
        var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
        tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
        uitex[3].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
    }).Send();
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
    {
        dealer_img += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;
        dealer_img += ",";
    }
    string[] newLinks = dealer_img.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < newLinks.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var index = i;  // We need to make a local copy because C# captures variables by reference to lambdas.
        new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("********************.amazonaws.com/resources/"
            + "dealer/pic/" + newLinks[index]),
            (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res)
            =>
            {
                var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
                tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
                uitex[index].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
            }).Send();
    }
```

It's weird but it works.

Comment: note that the capture as reference behaviour is not quite the actual behaviour, at least as of C#5 foreach loops use a different desugaring to provide the expected semantics: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16264289/1803692

Comment: No guarantee uitex is newLinks.Length.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a `foreach` here, you need to use a for-loop, since you have to know the index of the image to assign it to the correct texture.

```
// this line replaces the first for loop you have there
var textureLinks = tzPlayInfo.Instance.bcGameTables.Select(t => t.dlrimage).ToArray();
// verify we have enough uitex elements:
if (uitex.Length < textureLinks.Length) 
{
    throw new RuntimeException("too many textures linked");
}
for (int i = 0; i < textureLinks.Length; i++)
{
    new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri($"**.amazonaws.com/resources/dealer/pic/{textureLinks[i]}"),
        (req, res) => {
            var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
            tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
            uitex[i].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
        }).Send();
}
```

There's also some words to be lost on the naming convention you use.

`dealer_img` should be `dealerImg`, `uitex` should be `uiTextures`, `bc_gametablelist` should be `bcGameTables`, `dlrimage` should be `dealerImage`...

In general you seem to try to shorten your names and adhere to C++ conventions. That would be fine if you were programming the graphics in C++. But since this is C#, you should be following C# convention (namely `camelCase`)

In the code above I made use of interpolated strings for the Uri. I also left the variable types of the lambda up for inference by the compiler. It **should** be smart enough to do so, if BestHTTP properly specified the generics on `HTTPRequest`.

Comment: How could i seperate this one sir `**.amazonaws.com/resources` and `/dealer/pic` i need to seperate them for some purpose

Comment: and i have this error `Feature `interpolated strings' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification`

Comment: and it is still out of index sir.

Comment: The "Feature interpolates strings cannot be used" is fixed by using an up-to date version of the C# language. Update your project settings to use C#7 or newer. The "out of index" is pretty much impossible with the code I've provided. The only exception to that is if you did not in fact show the actual code you're using. Also "For some purpose" is **not** sufficent explanation. I can't mindread what your actual code is. You need to show your actual code.

Comment: @Vogel612 last time I checked Unity barely supported C#4 let alone C#7. But maybe things have changed since then. :)

Comment: @NikitaB According to the docs, unity supports .NET 4.x compiled profiles. That translates to C# 7 from 4.5 onwards. [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-7.468585/) implies that at least c#6 is supported and C#7 is in the making / partially supported

Comment: what do you mean by "*it is still out of index*" ?  you start the incrementation variable at `0` and loop until you loop the number of times equivalent to the number of items in the  `tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist`  collection

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that you are using a string variable to list images and then you create a string array and split the string variable into the array

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
> {
>     dealer_img += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;
>     dealer_img += ",";
> }
> string[] newLinks = dealer_img.Split(',');
> ```

you can actually skip a variable here and assign directly to the string array, like this

```
string[] newLinks = new string[tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
{
    newLinks[i] = tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;
}
```

This is probably more efficient than what you were doing, but I don't know what you were doing with `dealer_img` before the for loop because you haven't given the entire Method or Class.

because we use this value more than once I might add a variable to hold the count to make this code more readable as well.

```
int gameTableListCount = tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count;
string[] newLinks = new string[gameTableListCount];

for (int i = 0; i < gameTableListCount; i++)
{
    newLinks[i] = tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;
}
```

---

now if I am reading the rest of the code correctly, you should be able to move code into the for loop like @Vogel612 suggests.  if you need to do it without the interpolation then you could do it like this, keep in mind I did not change much of your original code:

```
int gameTableListCount = tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < gameTableListCount; i++)
{
    new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("**.amazonaws.com/resources/" 
            + "dealer/pic/" + tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage),
        (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res) =>
        {
            var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
            tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
            uitex[i].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
        }).Send();
}
```

I don't think there is anything else to suggest because you haven't provided the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

It is odd you add "," then split on it. This is inefficient as string is immutable.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append(tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage);
    sb.Append(",");
}
string[] newLinks = sb.ToString().Split(',');
```